# Disabling Sandbox for app not working

Tags: facebook, sandbox, user-permissions

Trying to use Facebook Connect to allow users to login to our new vBulletin 4.1.11 board.  It works fine, but only for people added ass Administrators, Testers, etc in the app.  As soon as a user is removed from the Admins/Testers, they get "An error occurred. Please try later" when trying to login.

It appears that the app is "stuck" in Sandbox mode, even though I have disabled Sandbox mode.

Thanks!

Comment: As of 2018-05-29 I cannot disable sandbox or development mode. I get server http error 500 from facebook